# What do we mean by if (!string) in C

Tags: c, pointers, operators, negation

I am trying to modify a code to adjust it to my liking. In order to do so I needed to understand what do we mean by if (!String) in C language if someone has any ideas ?

Example :

```c
const char *String;
if (!String) {
   //do something
}
```

Comment: It's the same thing as `if (String == NULL)`

Comment: `const char*` can be interpreted as a boolean when the value of the pointer > 0. The `!` operator inverses that result. So that check returns true when `String == 0`

Comment: If the value of the pointer is zero: i.e., it's null.

Comment: Note that in your snippet (taken as a whole program) `String` is not initialized or otherwise assigned a value. Testing with `if (!String)` (or otherwise inspecting its value) invokes UB.

Answer (score 0):

From the C Standard (6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators)

> 5 The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of
>   its operand compares  unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand
>   compares equal to 0. The result has type int.  The expression !E is
>   equivalent to (0==E).

And (6.3.2.3 Pointers)

> 3 An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an
>   expression cast to type  void *, is called a null pointer constant.
>   66) If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the
>   resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare
>   unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

So this if statement

```
if (!String) {
   //do something
}
```

checks whether the pointer `String` is equal to null-pointer provided that the pointer `String` was initialized.

While for example this statement

```
if (!*String) {
   //do something
}
```

checks whether the character pointed to by the pointer is equal to the null-terminating character `'\0'`.

If you'll include standard header `<iso646.h>` in your C-program then you can substitute the operator `!` for the word `not`.

For example

```
#include <iso646.h>

//...

if ( not String ) {
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a short way of writing `if(String == NULL)`.

Often we instead write `if(String)` which is short for `if(String != NULL)`. Note that this does NOT check if it points at a valid location. This code compiles but will (or may) fail:

```
char * str = strdup("Hello World!");
free(str);
if(str) { // If str is not a null pointer'
    puts(str); // str is pointing to memory that we have freed.
}
```

Trying to print str when it's no longer pointing at a valid location is undefined behavior. The program may print "Hello World!", crash or something else.